# how to create an folder in my project and download it automatically while clicking on button or link

Tags: javascript

I need to create a new folder automatically while clicking on the button

I tried using javascript

create folder

```
function CreateFolder(fn) {
            var myPath
            var oas = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");


        try {
            oas = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        } catch (e) // ActiveX control wasn't made
        {
            window
                    .alert("You must enable ActiveX Controls and press 'Yes' to each prompt");
        }
        myPath = "F:\New folder";
        oas.CreateFolder(myPath);
        alert("Helo");
        //insert_filename(fn);
    }
```

Comment: Is this for a webpage?

Comment: Where do you run this? Browser? WScript? Localhost, internet?
What is the error you're getting? ActiveXOBject is IE only, are  you running IE?
The \ in the myPath probably need to be escaped as \\.
But... help us help you and give important details on what (how it) is failing.

Comment: In Browser... Is there any possibility without using the above Script, because I am not running in IE.